# Ruby on Rails: how to check pluralized and single form of names

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, introspection, pluralize

I have created a model Anonymous with command

```
rails g model Anonymous section_id:integer aid:string fake:bool active:bool
```

but table name in the migration is called anonymous

```
class CreateAnonymous < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :anonymous do |t|
      t.integer :section_id
      t.string :aid
      t.bool :fake
      t.bool :active

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Am i right that pluralized form of Anonymous is Anomymous too ? (English is not my native language). How can i see what pluralized names Rails gives to my models ? Something like `rake routes` ?

Comment: The other answers talk about how the Rails pluralize stuff works, so you can see what the table name is. I'll add that in English, "anonymous" is an adjective, not a noun, and so doesn't normally have a plural form. Maybe you mean something like AnonymousUser or AnonymousComment?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this in the rails console.

```
$ "anonymous".pluralize
=> "anonymous"
```

or another example where the plural word is different.

```
$ "cookie".pluralize
=> "cookies"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pluralize(count, singular, plural = nil) public
```

Attempts to pluralize the singular word unless count is 1. If plural is supplied, it will use that when count is > 1, otherwise it will use the Inflector to determine the plural form

Examples:

```
pluralize(1, 'person')
# => 1 person

pluralize(2, 'person')
# => 2 people

pluralize(0, 'person')
# => 0 people
```

for you

```
"anonymous".pluralize
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd just rename your model. Save yourself the pain and future debugging and just avoid this potential headache.  You could use "Anonymouse" with plural "Anonymouses". Or think up a more clever name.