# How should I define uncountable noun in routes file?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I want to use uncountable noun in route file, how should I define it in route file? I would like to know common way as Rails.

```
resources :information, except: [:show]
```

Is the above correct?

Comment: Wines are countable.

Comment: Indeed... you can see how Rails will pluralize the string in your [Rails console](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13244248/398606): `"wine".pluralize` emits "wines".

Comment: sorry, I put incorrect line. not wine, I would like to ask about information

Comment: Thanks for your answer.

Comment: You should EDIT your Question

Answer (score 0):

Rails will use whatever `pluralize` returns.

In this case `wines` which is correct anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Rails deals well with non countable. So you can do this:

```
resources :information
```

Everything will work as expected!